# Using django query set values() to index into JSONField

Tags: json, django, postgresql, django-queryset

I am using django with postgres, and have a bunch of JSON fields (some of them quite large and detailed) within my model.  I'm in the process of switching from char based ones to jsonb fields, which allows me to `filter` on a key within the field, and I'm wondering if there is any way to get the equivalent benefit out of a call to the query set `values` method.

#### Example:

What I would like to do, given a `Car` model with `options` JSONField, is something like

```
qset = Car.objects.filter(options__interior__color='red')
vals = qset.values('options__interior__material')
```

Please excuse the lame toy problem, but hopefully it gets the idea across.  Here the `filter` call does exactly what I want, but the call to `values` does not seem to be aware of the special nature of the JSON field.  I get an error because `values` can't find the field called "interior" to join on.  Is there some other syntax or option that I am missing that will make this work?

Seems like a pretty obvious extension to the existing functionality, but I have so far failed to find any reference to something similar in the docs or through stack overflow or google searches.

#### Edit - a workaround:

After playing around, looks like this could be fudged by inserting the following in between the two lines of code above:

```
qset=qset.annotate(options__interior__material=RawSQL("SELECT options->'interior'->'material'",()))
```

I say "fudged" because it seems like an abuse of notation and would require special treatment for integer indices.

Still hoping for a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a better solution (for Django >= 1.11) is to use something like this:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields.jsonb import KeyTextTransform

Car.objects.filter(options__interior__color='red').annotate(
    interior_material=KeyTextTransform('material', KeyTextTransform('interior', 'options'))
).values('interior_material')
```

Note that you can nest `KeyTextTransform` expressions to pull out the value(s) you need.

Comment: Wow, been a little while.  I probably should have been a little more explicit in my question: I was looking for a general way of mapping string to operation so that I can lump this operation in along with a whole set of other `values` calls.  Still, I did not see `KeyTextTransform` which seems like the right way to handle the lookup.  Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 3):

I can suggest a bit cleaner way with using:

- django's `Func`
  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions
- and postgres function `jsonb_extract_path_text` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html

> ```
> from django.db.models import F, Func, CharField, Value
> Car.objects.all().annotate(options__interior__material =
>     Func(
>         F('options'),
>         Value('interior'),
>         Value('material'),
>         function='jsonb_extract_path_text'
>     ), 
> )
> ```

Comment: Thanks!  This is indeed a little cleaner (avoiding the call to `RawSQL`), although it still uses my abuse of notation (annotating with double underscores) and functionally it's almost the same (would be equivalent if I had used `#>` operator instead of `->` in the raw sql), right?  I wonder if the multiple index thing is more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

```
Car.objects.extra(select={'interior_material': "options#>'{interior, material}'"})
.filter(options__interior__color='red')
.values('interior_material')
```

You can utilize [`.extra()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#extra) and add postgres jsonb operators

Postgres jsonb operators: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-OP-TABLE